# Replica Set using MongoDB in Docker Container connecting to Node.js App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, replicaset

So, yeah..

I have these container runnning mongod and all the 3 of them were configured using `docker-compose` like this:

```
    version: '3.5'
 services: 
  mongodb-primary:
   container_name: mongodb-primary
   depends_on:                            
     - mongodb-secondary
     - mongodb-arbiter
   image: mongo
   ports:
   - "30001:27017"
networks:                              
  - mongo-cluster
command: "mongod --replSet mongo-rs"
```

same for the other one and the arbiter and then I got this setup.sh

```
     mongo-setup:
container_name: mongo-setup
image: mongo
depends_on:
  - mongodb-primary
  - mongodb-secondary
  - mongodb-arbiter
volumes:
  - ./scripts/mongosetup.sh:/scripts/mongosetup.sh      
networks:
  - mongo-cluster
command: "bash /scripts/mongosetup.sh"
```

and after this the network configuration of course.

Now, using: `docker exec -it mongodb-secondary mongo -eval "rs.status()"`

I get this:

```
    MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
    connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
    MongoDB server version: 4.0.0
    {
    "set" : "mongo-rs",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-08-24T17:28:25.422Z"),
    "myState" : 2,
    "term" : NumberLong(12),
    "syncingTo" : "mongodb-primary:27017",
    "syncSourceHost" : "mongodb-primary:27017",
    "syncSourceId" : 0,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "optimes" : {
            "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1535131703, 
     1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(12)
            },
            "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1535131703, 
     1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(12)
            },
            "appliedOpTime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1535131703, 
     1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(12)
            },
            "durableOpTime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1535131703, 
     1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(12)
            }
     },
     "lastStableCheckpointTimestamp" : 
     Timestamp(1535131683, 1),
         "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "name" : "mongodb- 
      primary:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 1,
                    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                    "uptime" : 2050,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : 
         Timestamp(1535131703, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(12)
                    },
                    "optimeDurable" : {
                            "ts" : 
         Timestamp(1535131703, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(12)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018- 
         08-24T17:28:23Z"),
                    "optimeDurableDate" : 
         ISODate("2018-08-24T17:28:23Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : 
         ISODate("2018-08-24T17:28:25.095Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : 
         ISODate("2018-08-24T17:28:24.433Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                    "syncingTo" : "",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "electionTime" : 
        Timestamp(1535129672, 1),
                    "electionDate" : 
        ISODate("2018-08-24T16:54:32Z"),
                    "configVersion" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "mongodb- 
         secondary:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 2055,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : 
        Timestamp(1535131703, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(12)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018- 
        08-24T17:28:23Z"),
                    "syncingTo" : "mongodb- 
        primary:27017",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "mongodb- 
        primary:27017",
                    "syncSourceId" : 0,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "configVersion" : 1,
                    "self" : true,
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "mongodb- 
        arbiter:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 7,
                    "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                    "uptime" : 2052,
                    "lastHeartbeat" : 
           ISODate("2018-08-24T17:28:25.095Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : 
           ISODate("2018-08-24T17:28:24.158Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                    "syncingTo" : "",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "configVersion" : 1
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1535131703, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
            "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1535131703, 1),
            "signature" : {
                    "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                    "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
            }
    }
    }
```

So, on my Node.js Application I try to connect to this replica set doing this:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
    const debug = require('debug') 
    ('app:adminRoutes');
    const books = [{'a bunch of stuff'}]
    const adminRouter = express.Router();

    function router(nav) {
    adminRouter.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
    const url = 'mongodb://'
  + 'localhost:30001,'
  + 'localhost:30002,'
  + '/libraryApp?replicaSet=mongo-rs&readPreference=secondaryPreferred';
    const dbName = 'libraryApp';
    (async function mongo() {
    let client;
    try {
      client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
      debug('Connected to the server');
      const db = client.db(dbName);
      const response = await 
      db.collection('books').insertMany(books);
      res.json(response);
      debug(nav);
    } catch (err) {
      debug(err.stack);
    }
    client.close();
    }());
    });
   return adminRouter;
    }
   module.exports = router;
```

And this is finally the problem I get. I'm not sure if the connection string is wrong or what, because all across the internet is done the same way. Could it be the async function doing this?

This is the output:

```
    [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
    app listening on port 4000 +0ms
    app:bookRoutes Trying to connect to MongoDB using MongoClient. +0ms



    ../node_modules/mongodb/lib/topologies/replset.js:368
          throw err;
          ^
```

Comment: would appreciate any help or point me in the right direction.

Could it be the fact that I can't use localhost for this? But yet, I've seen people using it. A DNS problem maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Use hostnames instead of 0.0.0.0, without port, i.e. `mongodb://mongodb-primary,mongodb-secondary/?replicaset=mongo-rs` and `docker-compose` will do all the networking.

Comment: Yeah, that does not work at all.

Still the same output.